# jquery check if returned value contains string

Tags: jquery, function, contain

I have a jquery on button click it runs a function in backend code. my code will return a string which may contain some values. Can I say if my string contains then means success otherwise show error(see my code below), the following code throws a syntax error:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "MyPage.aspx/MyFunction",
                    data: "{'totalToPay': '" + totalToPay + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (msg.d.contains('https://')) { // THIS IS WHERE IT THROWS ERROR. AM DOING THIS AS MY STRING MAY CONTAIN http://www.test.com
                            alert("TEST");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#error").show();
                            msgbox.html(msg.d);

                        }
                    }

                });
```

Comment: It would help if we knew what the server code returns. Also, what line throws the syntax error?

Comment: i suggest msg.d is throwing error here. there is no 'd' attached to msg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
msg.d.contains('https://')
```

You want:

```
msg.d.indexOf('https://') > -1
```

You're confusing [contains](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) with the jQuery DOM method.